# updateUserAttributes not working even after giving aws.cognito.signin.user.admin Oauth permission

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito

[image: Oauth Scope]

I have been working with AWS cognito and trying to update the `preferred_username` attribute.

I tried the `Auth.updateUserAttributes` call but in vain.

Here's the whole code :

```js
Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, {
    preferred_username: "new_username",
  })
    .then((data) => {
      setUser(data);
      console.log("updateUserAttributes succ", data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("updateUserAttributes err", error);
    });
})
.catch((r) => console.log("getUser err", r));
```

I have also checked the **app client settings** for read/write permission on the `preferred_username` attribute.
[image: Read/Write attribute settings]

Still I get this error :

```js
updateUserAttributes err Object {
  "code": "NotAuthorizedException",
  "message": "Access Token does not have required scopes",
  "name": "NotAuthorizedException",
}
```

I tried on other attributes as well, like `website` but I get the same response.

Thanks.

### Update

It seems user from external identity providers can't update their attributes [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/5921).

Can someone confirm or deny this ?